# Очистить две случайные колонны двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Из массива, допустим 4x6 уже заполненного, или в процессе заполнения нужно очистить две случайные колонны, как это можно реализовать?

второстепенный вопрос, как можно задать лимит используемых случайных символов? что бы каждого было максимум по четыре

вот из такого:

```c
   int r = 4;
    int c = 6;
    char pole[r][c];
    srand(time(NULL));
    char symb[] = "ABCD";
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++, putchar('\n'))
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {

            pole[r][c] = symb[rand() % 4];
            printf("'%c'", pole[r][c]);
        }
}

 'B' 'D' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'C'
 'B' 'C' 'B' 'A' 'C' 'B'
 'A' 'B' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'B'
 'A' 'A' 'C' 'A' 'D' 'C'
```

сделать такое:

```
 'B' ' ' ' ' 'C' 'D' 'C'
 'B' ' ' ' ' 'A' 'C' 'B'
 'A' ' ' ' ' 'A' 'B' 'B'
 'A' ' ' ' ' 'A' 'D' 'C'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как выбрать две случайные колонки?

Comment: в том, как их очистить) именно колонну, есть идея что выбирается случайный индекс из первой строки, очищать его, или заменять на пробел, и добавлять к этому индексу значение колонн, если вторую колонну,  то 2 + 6, и так до конца